# How to Unit testing Angular4 HttpClient Service for both success and error condition

Tags: angular

New to angular I need help to unit test this code to get full coverage. I'm trying to verifying mock response return by promise but getting `undefined` every time.

```
getData(): Promise<{}> {
    const apiUrl = 'resources/data.json';
    return this.http
      .get(apiUrl)
      .toPromise()
      .then(this.extractData)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  private extractData(res: any) {
    return res;
  }

  private handleError(error: any) {
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
}
```

Comment: const apiUrl = 'resources/data.json';
    return this.http
      .get(apiUrl)

Does this alone return anything? Are you getting a success 200 for retrieving the json?

Comment: @Taranjitkang -- Yes I'm getting json response from above code. This code is working fine n ng serve but failing in ng test.